# Chebyshev polynomial multiplication with size reduction

Tags: polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

I have two one dimensional functions which are represented by some polynomial expansions (let's assume Chebyshev polynomials)

$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{N} f_k T_k(x)$ and $g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{N} g_k T_k(x)$.

I need to multiply these two expansions. It is known that the result will be some new $2N$ degree polynomial

$s(x)=f(x) g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{2N}s_kT_k(x)$,

with coefficients $s_k$ which can be calculated by known algorithms.

My questions is whether it is possible to somehow reduce the degree of final expansion? Namely, I am interested to obtain resulting expansion of the same $N$ degree rather $2N$. So I am looking for some algorithm which is able to transform original $\{s_k\}_{k=0}^{2N}$ coefficients to some new set $\{\tilde{s}_k\}_{k=0}^{N}$ with reduced dimension and still good enough to represent function of interest with reasonable precision.

Comment: I think "degree" might not be what you want to say, I think you mean that you want an expansion of the form $\sum_{k=0}^N a_k T_{\sigma(k)}(x)$ for some injective function $\sigma : \{ 0,1,\dots,N \} \to \{ 0,1,\dots,2N \}$. Or something like this.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm not a real mathematician, so the terminology can be not very accurate.

Comment: Well, you need some restriction on the polynomials $f,g$. Otherwise it is pretty futile.